# Formality of 'but' at the end of the sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I quite often use 'but' at the end of sentence, and I've seen it elsewhere.

for example:

> Yeah, it sounds like you guys had an awesome last night! I did get a lot of work done but.

Is this common? Is it formal English? Where else is it used?

Comment: It's ungrammatical.

Comment: It's grammatical, common, not very formal. I think *but* in such a sentence is more of an adverb or interjection than a conjunction. But other people might argue that it's a conjunction that's been moved.

Comment: It's not English, to my ear at least. FWIW: The only times I have seen it used, it was written by Swedish people in English emails. Dunno whether that anecdotal info is significant or helpful. Perhaps there is a similar construction in Swedish? Just a guess.

Comment: Definitely not formal. It's a very unusual construction or expression, one I'm unfamiliar with and. :)

Comment: @Kris, Drew, It's not standard Gen Am or RP, but it's completely grammatical in many varieties of English, notably several of those in Ireland, Scotland, Australia and NewZealand. dwjohnston, are you from any of these places by any chance?

Comment: It is not grammatical to my American ear. An American speaker would say, _I did get a lot of work done, though._

Comment: @curiousdannii How do you define "grammatical," by the way?

Comment: @Kris according to my own personal subjective grammaticality judgements :) I should've said that it's grammatical in AusEn.

Comment: I've never heard this usage (as a true final word) in American English. We do have a form in which "but" is followed by an elesion to represent an implied completion of the sentence, but that's inflected as such.

Comment: Though Collins is progressive enough to label 'however' a [contrastive] 'sentence connector' in say 'I do drink. However, I never have more than 4 units a day.', it doesn't suggest what we should call this 'however': 'My brother can drink a bottle of wine at one go, however.' [a postponed contrastive sentence connector?] 'Though' and 'sentence-final but' are comparable, and usually have similar meanings. Sentence-initial but obviously refers to previous context, making it a sentence connector also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Though the *but* here apparently corresponds to the familiar *though,* such usage of *but* is not standard; it seems to be a regionalism. See also my comments at Auraucaria's answer below.

Comment: @Kris I'm trying to classify the POS, not decide where it's acceptable. Sentence-final 'though' is doubtless cast as an adverb in most dictionaries, but I'm fighting the 'adverbs modify only verbs' campaign. It (and s-f but) does seem to have the role of a contrastive sentence connector, just as if it were sentence-initial. The postponed positioning available for 'though' and 'however with any necessary comma' may be encouraging this broadened distribution for 'but'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sentence-final but* as it is known is a well documented feature of English as spoken in Ireland, much of Scotland and also in Australia and New Zealand. Although it is perfectly grammatical, it is not considered formal and won't be seen in formal writing or documents. It has been the subject of many academic papers in linguistics and a few books. If you'd like to read up on it, here's a source to get you going:

- Mulder & Thompson, 2008, 'The grammaticization of *but* as a final particle in English conversation' in Ritva Laury *Studies in clause combining*. John Benjamins. pp. 179-204.

Comment: Please pay particular attention to the use of "grammaticization," (rather than 'grammaticality') in the title. See also: https://benjamins.com/#catalog/books/slcs.162.12han/details "The examination of the various semantic-pragmatic meanings shows that they can directly be put along a specific grammaticalization chain and that instead of being explainable in terms of pragmaticalization, they can be better explained in terms of cooptation and grammaticalization. "

Comment: Final *but* in Australian English conversation  http://books.google.co.in/books?id=leE5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA339

Comment: @Kris They have to be grammatical before they can become grammaticalized!!!!

Comment: Think again, esp., the (lack of) logic of your last statement.

Comment: @Kris I don't see why you reckon there's a lack of logic there. You do get what grammaticalised means, right? It doesn't mean 'made grammatical', if that's what you were getting at?

Answer (score 2):

You will hear this in the parts of the  Midlands and north of England, possibly Wales, but you will not hear it in the South. There, you're more likely to hear 'innit' or 'bruv' than 'but', 'innit' in particular being an even more pointless addition to a sentence - generally, in parts of the country where the use of 'but' at the end of a sentence does not occur, it can cause confusion or be thought of as quaint but peculiar. Geordies in particular often use but in this way, as in "she's a canny lass, but", where it doesn't mean anything other than a full stop. Certainly, neither would appear in formal print.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that in my experience as a 19-year-old American girl in the Northeast (MD and DC mostly), I use and hear this a lot. Maybe it's spreading!

It's definitely informal/casual usage, though, and mostly meant to imply something depending on context, letting the reader/listener fill in the blanks for themselves.

Here, you might often hear "...but yeah" or "...but whatever" as a finish to the sentence, so sometimes the "yeah/whatever" gets dropped off, leaving "but" to end the sentence. This may or may not be what's happening.

But I'll give some examples to show what I mean:

Example one, unvoiced "yeah" and continuation of thought:

> -Did you do your homework? 
>   -I had a lot of trouble with solving the formulas, **but**... *yeah, I did the homework, although it might not be 100% correct.*

Example two, unvoiced "whatever", dismissal of topic:

> -My cat is officially a jerk, she keeps knocking over my stuff for cat reasons. And here I thought I was going to finally clean my room, **but**. *whatever, let's talk about something else.* OR *whatever, we know that's not going to happen.*

Example three, implication that the opposite will occur and/or a dismissal of topic:

> -What did that guy want? 
>   -He's my brother; wanted me to give him a ride home, **but**. *that's not happening.*

I'd like to note that the final "but" may rise or fall in pitch so that it sounds like it ends in a question (as it might with example one) or sounds final (as with examples two and three).