# Informal Australian use of "as" at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, colloquialisms, australian-english, sentence-ends

In Australia I have heard expressions such as “It's fully stressful *as*.” and “All are really skux(?) *as*.”

What is the meaning or force of this use of “as” at the end of a sentence?

Comment: I believe it's a variation on "as fuck" etc. Definitely slang or colloquial. Can't find any references.

Comment: @StuartF is correct about meaning. As an Australian, never use it in a formal setting, and avoid it when speaking to older people. OK with younger people in an informal setting.

Comment: Are you suggesting either "it's fully stressful as…" or "all are really skux as…" is a sentence? Broadly, they're not. Since neither is more than a phrase, how could the Question be valid?

Comment: Can you rephrase 'I ever heard…'? As it stands, that isn't intelligible.

Comment: There's [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199707/formality-of-but-at-the-end-of-the-sentence) about Australians ending sentences with "but" which functions as an adverb expressing doubt or moderating the rest of the sentence, like "maybe". Australians really like shortening things (see also "arvo", "convo", etc). I've tried to Google for sentence-final "as" but I'm not getting anything useful, just lots of results which use "as" rather than discussing it.

Comment: It’s used in New Zealand too. When you start a sentence intending to make a metaphor but nothing comes to mind then you are as stranded as….